# Convert css code => transform: translate(-50%, -50%) to tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there any way to `convert` the code `=> transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to `tailwindcss`. I have searched up the tailwindcss docs but there is no solution to this.

Answer (score 6):

Tailwind has **[translate classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/translate#basic-usage)**. To use negative values you just need to prefix the class with `-`

`-translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2`

Comment: You can't use both of the utility classes at the same time. They override each other, as they're both changing the same property `transform`.

Comment: @yamanidev No, you **can** use both `translate-x` and `translate-y` utilities together. There is no conflict. This answer is correct.

Comment: That's correct yes. My mistake.

Comment: All good! That's what StackOverflow is here for 

Comment: I'm encountering the issue @yamanidev mentioned. Taildind simply overrides `transform` value:

```.-translate-y-1\/2 {
    --tw-translate-y: -50%;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x);
}```
with `.-translate-x-1\/2 {
    --tw-translate-x: -50%;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x);
}`

Comment: @IvanZakharchuk Technically the transform property is indeed overridden, but that does not cause trouble, either value of is valid (they're identical).

What's happening here is that the variables change (`--tw-translate-x` and `--tw-translate-y`), and that's what the `transform` property is using.